# How to return a dictionary composed of the number of occurrences of each word of 2 letters

Tags: python, function, dictionary, key, find-occurrences

> Write a function that prints the dictionary in the following manner:
>
> Key : GT - Value : 1
> Key : CT - Value : 8

---

Code:

```
def occurrences2letters(sequence): 
    dico = {}
    for i in range(len(sequence)-1): 
          key = sequence[i]+sequence[i+1] 
          dico[key] = dico.get(key,0) + 1
     return dico
```

I got `{'AC': 1, 'CC': 3, 'CT': 8, 'TA': 7, 'AG': 7, 'GC': 7, 'CA': 1, 'AT': 2, 'TG': 2, 'GT': 1, 'GA': 1, 'AA': 1, 'TC': 2, 'CG': 1, 'GG': 1, 'TT': 2}`

Now I want another code helping me to have the result showed in the beginning. For the moment I have written that part of the code but it doesn't work

```
def printDico(dico):
      for key in dico:
          print("Key : "+str(key)+" - Value : "+str(dico[key]))
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: I am not able to get the dict in that format Key : GT - Value : 1 Key : CT - Value : 8.

Comment: Do you actually call your function `printDico()`? Because it works - printing all keys and values in the expected format. Give more details as to what exactly is the problem - e.g. do you get error, what get printed, etc.

Comment: I think you should use for key in ['GT, 'CT'] for producing the desired output.

Comment: Also note that we are not able to comment on `occurrences2letters()` because we have no info as to what your sequence looks like and if the sample `dico` is what is expected

Comment: The info about occurence2letters() is dico = occurrences2letters("ACCTAGCCATGTAGAATCGCCTAGGCTTTAGCTAGCTCTAGCTAGCTG"). In fact I dont know how to call the second part of the code with printDico in order to show the result I want. Should it be separated from the previous code or not separeted ? Could you show me how you got a result @buran

Answer (score 0):

```
def occurrences2letters(sequence): 
    dico = {}
    for i in range(len(sequence)-1): 
        key = sequence[i]+sequence[i+1] 
        dico[key] = dico.get(key,0) + 1
    return dico

def printDico(dico):
    for key in dico:
        print("Key : "+str(key)+" - Value : "+str(dico[key]))

spam = "ACCTAGCCATGTAGAATCGCCTAGGCTTTAGCTAGCTCTAGCTAGCTG"
dico = occurrences2letters(spam)
printDico(dico)
```

output:

```
Key : AC - Value : 1
Key : CC - Value : 3
Key : CT - Value : 8
... some output left out for brevity
Key : CG - Value : 1
Key : GG - Value : 1
Key : TT - Value : 2
```

Your `occurrences2letters()` returns a dict, you first need to call it, passing your string as argument, then call `printDico()` passing the dict from the first function as argument.

Note, there are better ways to do what you did, using e.g. `collections.Counter`, more pythonic way to iterate over key, value pairs of a dict, etc.

```
import collections
import more_itertools # third-party library, instaled from pypi
spam = "ACCTAGCCATGTAGAATCGCCTAGGCTTTAGCTAGCTCTAGCTAGCTG"

for key, value in collections.Counter(more_itertools.windowed(spam, 2)).items():
    print(f'Key: {"".join(key)} - Value: {value}')
```